# iOS how to introduce an ability for a class to have UDID without subclassing everything?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, nsobject, udid

I'm working with keyed archiving and found that there's a need for some of my objects to have universal identifier. I'm thinking of introducing UDID for this purpose.

I can create a custom class like this and have my objects inherit from this, but this means multiple implementations of udid. I would like to have only one.

```
@interface NSObjectWithUDID : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong,readonly)NSString* udid;

@end
```

My question is: **How can I add an ability for my classes to respond to [udid]** message without having to subclass NSObjectWithUDID?

I tried categories, but am not sure if I can use a property there.

Comment: I think you mean GUID, not UDID.

Comment: or UUID (GUID are effectively a Microsoft implementation of UUID)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that you cant add a property in a Category, but you can do a runtime set using objc runtime methods

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
static char udidKey;

@implementation NSObject (UDIDAddition)

- (NSString *)udid {
   return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &udidKey);
}

- (void)setUdid:(NSString *)udid {
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &udidKey, udid, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

@end
```

Comment: You can add properties to categories, they just can't have backing variables. If the UDID is somehow calculated, adding a property to the category interface is fine. You would just implement the getter (and setter if not readonly) yourself, like in your example.

Comment: True, but storage/retrieval would probably be much faster for most udid generation methods

Comment: This is a very good solution to the problem. I have a general-purpose category of NSObject that has methods setAsscValueForkey and asscValueForKey that lets you add key/value pairs to an object at will using associative storage. It works like a charm. For something like this where you have a specific property you need to add, creating a property getter/setter backed by associative storage is ideal.

Comment: UDID is lazily instantiated, and that requires a backing variable, as far as I understand.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think this means multiple implementations of `udid`?

If you have classes `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. which inherit from `NSObject` and you switch them all to inherit from `NSObjectWithUDID` instead then there is just one implementation of `udid` - and it is implemented for you by the compiler.

You are correct, adding a property using a category is non-trivial - but it can be done using *associated objects*. However there appears to be no need to go that route here.

HTH

Comment: That works unless some of the classes that you want to have UUIDs are system-defined classes.

Comment: Some of the classes that I will be subclassing are from the SpriteKit framework, and I can only inherit from them, like SKSpriteNode. Your solution is what I have right now, I was just thinking there might be something better.

Comment: @AlexStone - If that is the case then go with associated objects - they provide the "backing variable" you need, just do your normal lazy instantiation in the getter.